# jQuery parallax background image skips on first scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

I have implemented a simple jQuery parallax script into my site. When a div has the class 'parallax' and the following data `data-type="background" data-speed="8"` the script that handles the parallax motion will act.

My issue is that when the page loads, on first scroll, the background image jumps. Is there a way around this?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $window = $(window);
    var $containerHeight = $('section[data-type="background"]').height();

    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){

        var $bgobj = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'))-($containerHeight/2); 

            // Put together our final background position
            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            // Move the background
            $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
        }); 
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evpt5m2d/9/

Comment: A fiddle says a thousand words.

Comment: @Shikkediel - here it is http://jsfiddle.net/evpt5m2d/9/

Comment: ah yes, that does work nicely now - nice and easy - thanks mate

Comment: Sorry, deleted the earlier comment before I saw the reply, wanting to make sure it was what you meant...

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to offset the background image so it makes the image look more central on smaller divs - but that's just a minor, the main thing is to stop the jump!